# Extend the certificate length for my machine

Tags: ssl, identityserver3, self-signed

I am trying to configure my certificates for Identity Server. They require a minimum length of 2048 bits.

When I try to use the certificate for my machine which is the only one that seems to be accepted but throws an error saying it's not long enough. How can I extend the length?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make your own certificate. Check out this [article](https://brockallen.com/2015/06/01/makecert-and-creating-ssl-or-signing-certificates/). There are many tools and articles on how to do this. For testing you can use [this](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/MVC%20Authentication/EmbeddedMvc/IdentityServer) and [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/MVC%20Authentication/EmbeddedMvc/Startup.cs#L143) is the cert password.

Comment: I have done but the current one for my machine is the only one that is accepted... and I don't want to delete it and make another incase it breaks stuff